# Swift 3 suggested correction for "cannot convert value for '(CKAccountStatus, NSError?) -> ()' to '... -> Void'

Tags: swift, swift3, cloudkit

I am getting the error `cannot convert value for '(CKAccountStatus, NSError?) -> ()' to '(CKAccountStatus, NSError?) -> Void'` on the third line of the function.

Here is the code:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    container.accountStatusWithCompletionHandler{
        (status: CKAccountStatus, error: NSError?) in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            var title: String!
            var message: String!
            if error != nil{
                title = "Error"
                message = "An error occurred = \(error)"
            } else {
                //title = "No errors occurred getting info"
                switch status{
                case .Available:
                    message = "The user is logged in to iCloud"
                    title = "GOOD"
                    print("determined status was available")
                    self.shouldPullFromICloud()
                //self.displayAlertWithTitle(title, message: message)
                case .CouldNotDetermine:
                    message = "Could not determine if the user is logged" +
                    " into iCloud or not"
                    title = "BAD"
                    self.noUserIsSignedIn()
                case .NoAccount:
                    message = "User is not logged into iCloud"
                    title = "BAD"
                    self.noUserIsSignedIn()
                case .Restricted:
                    message = "Could not access user's iCloud account information"
                    title = "BAD"
                    self.noUserIsSignedIn()
                }
                print(title, message)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Now Xcode is offering a 'fix it' by inserting "as! (CKAccountStatus, Error?) -> Void" on the second to last line. This doesn't help and it just keeps asking me if I want to 'fix it' and if I click it it will just keep tacking on more and more "as! (CKAccountStatus, Error?) -> Void"s. Here is what it looks like after a single click of the 'fix it' button:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    container.accountStatusWithCompletionHandler{
        (status: CKAccountStatus, error: NSError?) in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            var title: String!
            var message: String!
            if error != nil{
                title = "Error"
                message = "An error occurred = \(error)"
            } else {
                //title = "No errors occurred getting info"
                switch status{
                case .Available:
                    message = "The user is logged in to iCloud"
                    title = "GOOD"
                    print("determined status was available")
                    self.shouldPullFromICloud()
                //self.displayAlertWithTitle(title, message: message)
                case .CouldNotDetermine:
                    message = "Could not determine if the user is logged" +
                    " into iCloud or not"
                    title = "BAD"
                    self.noUserIsSignedIn()
                case .NoAccount:
                    message = "User is not logged into iCloud"
                    title = "BAD"
                    self.noUserIsSignedIn()
                case .Restricted:
                    message = "Could not access user's iCloud account information"
                    title = "BAD"
                    self.noUserIsSignedIn()
                }
                print(title, message)
            }
        })
    } as! (CKAccountStatus, Error?) -> Void
}
```

Comment: Just change this one `(status: CKAccountStatus, error: NSError?) in` with `(status: CKAccountStatus, error: Error?) in` and remove `as! (CKAccountStatus, Error?) -> Void` one.

Comment: I'm still getting the repetitive error and the 'fix it'

Answer (score 0):

**Reason for the error.**

This happened to me when I updated my project to swift 3.0 or a cocoapod. To fix this copy the method code and then redeclare it using autocomplete and then place the code back inside. The error is a bit vague but this is because the declaration has changed.

**Quick Fix**

Specifically the declaration now uses Error not NSError. So change the line:

```
(status: CKAccountStatus, error: NSError?) in
```

To:

```
(status: CKAccountStatus, error: Error?) in
```

**Full Fix (Requested by OP)**

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    container.accountStatus{
        (status: CKAccountStatus, error: Error?) in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            var title: String!
            var message: String!
            if error != nil{
                title = "Error"
                message = "An error occurred = \(error)"
            } else {
                //title = "No errors occurred getting info"
                switch status{
                case .Available:
                    message = "The user is logged in to iCloud"
                    title = "GOOD"
                    print("determined status was available")
                    self.shouldPullFromICloud()
                //self.displayAlertWithTitle(title, message: message)
                case .CouldNotDetermine:
                    message = "Could not determine if the user is logged" +
                    " into iCloud or not"
                    title = "BAD"
                    self.noUserIsSignedIn()
                case .NoAccount:
                    message = "User is not logged into iCloud"
                    title = "BAD"
                    self.noUserIsSignedIn()
                case .Restricted:
                    message = "Could not access user's iCloud account information"
                    title = "BAD"
                    self.noUserIsSignedIn()
                }
                print(title, message)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay so deleting the code worked in that if gave me a different 'fix it' error which after clicking worked! However now my code is, instead of "accountStatusWithCompletionHandler{" is only "accountStatus{". Do I need the completion handler? It says I could use "accoutnStatus(completion: )" but I don't know how to put my code in the completion handler or what it's really doing honestly

Comment: Yes, you still need the competition handler and it is still there. They have just changed the naming convention and dropped the WithCompletionHandler to shorten the declaration.

Comment: Would you mind showing me how it would look placing the code within the (completion: ) part of the code? I can't seem to get it to work. Would everything go inside those parenthesis?

Comment: I've added the full fix in my original answer so you can just copy and paste it. :)

Answer (score 0):

First two things:

`accountStatusWithCompletionHandler(_:)` has renamed to `accountStatus(completionHandler:)` in Swift 3.

[func accountStatus(completionHandler: (CKAccountStatus, Error?) -> Void)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/cloudkit/ckcontainer/1399180-accountstatus)

And as already commented, the type of the completeHandler has changed:

`completionHandler: @escaping (CKAccountStatus, Error?) -> Void`

When supplying a closure argument with closure expression, you have no need to worry about `@escaping`.

So, you need to replace these two lines:

```
    container.accountStatusWithCompletionHandler{
        (status: CKAccountStatus, error: NSError?) in
```

With these:

```
    container.accountStatus {
        (status: CKAccountStatus, error: Error?) in
```

You may find many other parts you need to fix in Swift 3, but with the two above fixed, Xcode will give you a better suggestion.

(Do not forget to remove `as! (CKAccountStatus, Error?) -> Void`, before testing the code above.)

Comment: Do I not need to use the (completion: ) part? I can just use the .accountStatus?

Comment: @lelephant, when using trailing closure syntax, you can omit the parameter label `completionHandler:`. When you use normal method call syntax, you need it -- `container.accountStatus(completionHandler: {...})`.

Comment: Can you explain what trailing closure syntax is? Based on my code which would be better to use?

Comment: @lelephant, in your code, `container.accountStatusWithCompletionHandler{...}`, it's "trailing closure". You need `()` to call methods normally. So, it can be written as `container.accountStatusWithCompletionHandler({...})` in Swift 2, using normal method call. You sometimes need to use normal method call (for example in `if`-condition clause), but other than that, I prefer using trailing closure syntax. Check [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID102).